# libreoffice macro - toggle enablevisible on a textfield

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'm using python macro to do things to a libreoffice writer file. And I'd like a possibility to toggle the EnableVisible flag of a TextField.

That means, toggle the little flag that you can use, when double clicking on that field, to make it visible or invisible.

So far I got this in my code :

```
import uno

def toggle_field(field_title):
    document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    textfields = document.getTextFields()
    enum = textfields.createEnumeration()
    while enum.hasMoreElements():
        tf = enum.nextElement()
        if tf.VariableName == field_title:
            visibility = tf.getPropertyValue('EnableVisible') #wrong
            tf.EnableVisible = not visibility                 #wrong
            tf.update()                                       #maybe right
```

This give me that

> com.sun.star.beans.UnknownPropertyException: Unknown property: Enabled (Error during invoking function toggle_field in module (...)file.py (: Unknown property: EnableVisible

Also, if i comment te first wrong line, the second wrong line give me

> com.sun.star.beans.UnknownPropertyException: Unknown property: Enabled (Error during invoking function toggle_field in module (...)file.py (: EnableVisible

---

update :

```
tf.IsFieldDisplayed = False
```

or

```
tf.setPropertyValue('IsFieldDisplayed', False)
```

is no longer an unknown property, but i got this error message :

> com.sun.star.beans.UnknownPropertyException: IntrospectionAccessStatic_Impl::setPropertyValueByIndex(), property at index 13 is readonly (Error during invoking function toggle_field in module (...)file.py (: IntrospectionAccessStatic_Impl::setPropertyValueByIndex(), property at index 13 is readonly

what seems unfair, because it is not readonly in the doc, and BASIC can modify it (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/b/b0/BH5009-Macros.pdf page 19)

Comment: How about `tf.IsFieldDisplayed = not tf.IsFieldDisplayed`?

Comment: where are you finding your doc or your ideas ? do you know a secret doc ? reading uno source code ?

Comment: The docs of OpenOffice are slightly better (although not great either): https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextField.html#XPropertySet

Comment: What does your `tf` object look like? Could you give us the output of `dir(tf)`?

Comment: there it is : http://dpaste.com/2BD23PA Yeah, the isvisible field is not readonly, solution found, dir was awesome in that situation :)

Comment: Thanks, there is a `IsVisible` property, did you try that already?

Comment: yeah, it works :) thank you a lot
do you want to write the solution to get a lot of good points ?

Comment: Also answered at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/156960/python-macro-toggle-enablevisible-on-a-textfield/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a common research effort, it turns out that the property is called `IsVisible`:

```
 tf.IsVisible = not tf.IsVisible
```