# Libreoffice Base macro - How to make visible/hide a control on a form?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

I created a database Form with 2 comboboxes, `Combo1` and `Combo2`.
`Combo2` visibility depends on `Combo1` status: `Combo1` checked, `Combo2` visible; `Combo1` unchecked, `Combo2` hidden.

I expected to find something like `Combo2.setVisible(Combo1.isVisible())` but I have been too optimist.

This is the macro I have been playing with:

```
Sub MyMacro(oEvent as Object)
    msgbox(oEvent.Source.getState())   rem returns Checked/Unchecked status of Combo1
    msgbox(oEvent.source.model.Name)   rem Name of the Event generator (Combo1)
End Sub
```

```
cb2 = ThisComponent.Drawpage.Forms.getByName("MainForm").getByName("Combo2")
msgbox(cb2.Name)
```

prints correctly `Combo2`, so I assume I have a proper reference...

And now?

Today is the very first day I play with Libreoffice Base (and its bugs), and this is just something nice that I would like to add for tomorrow's demo. I NEVER used before a macro both in Microsoft nor Libreoffice suites, so I am moving veeery slow.

Last time I used BASIC was probably around 1990.

I went through a number of tutorials online (usually based on Libreoffice Calc cells), string-searched both main books by Andrew Pitonyak ("Useful Macro Information For OpenOffice.org" and "OpenOffice.org Macros Explained (OOME)") but after trying tons of snippets I got nowhere.

Same for [libreoffice macro - toggle enablevisible on a textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679134/libreoffice-macro-toggle-enablevisible-on-a-textfield)

Any pointer?

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with Basic, then try [Python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python) which is a popular macro language for LibreOffice. [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) helps get started.

Comment: Can't answer your specific Q, but if you're going to be using base basic, I think you really need to be using this if you aren't already:  https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool  It took me a little while to learn to use it, and I even then rewrote the manual for it a bit, but I found it very helpful.  Here is the best manual for it:  https://github.com/hanya/MRI/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working snippet (not guaranteed to be the most straightforward, as my experience with macros is one day long):

```
Sub SetVisibility(oEvent as Object)
    cb2 = ThisComponent.Drawpage.Forms.getByName("MainForm").getByName("Combo2")
    cb2.enableVisible = oEvent.Source.getState()   
    rem the action is activated by Combo1, the event source
End Sub
```